# How to remove parentheses and comma from printed output

Tags: python

Edit: Apparently I was using python 2. Switching to 3 fixed the issue and now I am getting the proper results without the parentheses/commas. Thanks for the replies - problem solved :D

Beginner at Python and coding in general. Struggling with my first project assignment, but I've gotten so close on my own.

My assignment is to create a code in python that counts the number of coins from a given value i.e. quarters, nickels, dimes, pennies.

My initial code looks like this:

```
coins=input('Enter amount of change: ')
print("Quarters", coins//25)
coins = coins%25
print("Dimes", coins//10)
coins = coins%10
print("Nickles", coins//5)
coins = coins%5
print('Pennies', coins//1)
```

Which prompts something like, "Enter amount of change: 86"
('Quarters', 3)
('Dimes', 1)
('Nickles', 0)
('Pennies', 1)

These are the correct values, but my instructor wants it to look like this:

Enter amount of change: 86
Quarters: 3
Dimes: 1
Nickles" 0
Pennies: 1

I can get the colon in there, but how can I remove the parentheses and commas? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: You are obviously using Python 2 where `print` is a statement yet. In recent Python 2 version you can use the appropriate `from future import ...` command to switch it to function mode. The precise form of the command is left to the reader :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to produce the required output. For example for quarters:

```
print('Quarters: {}'.format(coins//25))
```

This will work in both versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I've always used to print values in Python 2, which is the Python version you appear to be using, is the following:

```
coins=int(input('Enter amount of change: '))
print "Quarters: %i" % (coins//25)
coins = coins%25
print "Dimes: %i" % (coins//10)
coins = coins%10
print "Nickles: %i" % (coins//5)
coins = coins%5
print 'Pennies: %i' % (coins//1)
```

The `%` symbol, when used with strings, allows whatever value you want to be printed to be substituted in the string.  To substitute multiple values, you separate them with commas.  For example:

```
someInt = 1
someStr = 'print me!'
print "The values are %i and %s" % (someInt, someStr)
```

This code will substitute in `someInt` and `someStr` for `%i` (used for integers) and `%s` (used for strings), respectively.

However, the `%` symbol also functions as the modulus operator, so it does 2 different things when it is being used with strings and when it is being used among two numbers.

Comment: Is not neccesary add parentheses to one argument at `%`

Comment: Actually, I was getting errors when I didn't include them @kip.  I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that division is also being performed after the `%` in the code, and so the parentheses ensure that the operations are being carried out in the right order.

Comment: Yes, you are right !, i forgot the math operation, but with a simple number or string is possibly ! some ex: `print '%d' % 5`

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
coins=input('Enter amount of change: ')
print "Quarters:",coins//25
coins = coins%25
print "Dimes:",coins//10
coins = coins%10
print "Nickles:",coins//5
coins = coins%5
print "Pennies:",coins//1
```

Comment: This answer does not work in Python 3, but it is definitely the simplest solution for Python 2!

Comment: Your answer would be better if you took the time to explain what you did differently. Otherwise, anyone reading your answer has to compare the code to the question line by line and character by character.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Python 2. I think you intended to use Python 3 given your use of `input()` and `print()` methods, but the code will work in Python 2 by changing `print()` methods to `print` *keywords*. Your code would look like the following in "proper"* Python 2:

```
coins = input('Enter amount of change: ')
print 'Quarters: ' + str(coins // 25)
coins = coins % 25
print 'Dimes: ' + str(coins // 10)
coins = coins % 10
print 'Nickles: ' + str(coins // 5)
coins = coins % 5
print 'Pennies: ' + str(coins)
```

Hope this helped!

*Footnote: Using `%` is preferred over using string concatenation, but I still believe that it is easier to read for beginners this way.*

Comment: Is a bad practice concatenate the str with `+`, you can use the simple format `'%s %d' % (string, number)`......

Comment: @kip Added a footnote. :)

Answer (score 0):

To use the `print()` syntax on python2 add this to the top of your program:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

otherwise python will interpret the argument to `print` as a tuple and you'll see ().

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python 3 and the following lines exactly give what your instructor wants:

```
coins=float(input("Enter amount of change: "))
print("Quarters:", round(coins//25))
coins = coins%25
print("Dimes:", round(coins//10))
coins = coins%10
print("Nickels:", round(coins//5))
coins = coins%5
print("Pennies: %.0f" % coins)
```

Comment: The `round()` is redundant due to integer division.

Comment: Apparently I was on 2. Upgraded to Python 3 and now I am getting the expected results. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: No problem, @MasonMoose. Hope it helped.

Comment: @Jerrybibo, print("Quarters:", coins//25) still gives Quaters: 3.0 not Quarters: 3 Since Mason asked for a specific format, round() is not redundant.

Comment: @wthimdh I can't seem to reproduce the results you are having.

Comment: @Jerrybibo, I used float() before input() so that it does not crush if the user enters something like 86.5. Maybe, that's the reason?

Comment: @wthimdh Ahhh, that was the issue - I see why now. But it doesn't seem logical that someone would have half a penny at their disposal :P

Comment: it was just a suggestion to Mason:) he does not need to use that.