# Why Python is outputting parenthesis and quotes in my print command?

Tags: python

I noticed my python script is printing parenthesis and quotes, for example the line:

```
print ("Password set saved on file:", ps_file_name)
```

outputs the following:

```
('Password set saved on file:', '20180531-1719__password_set.txt')
```

while the intended result would be:

```
Password set saved on file: 20180531-1719__password_set.txt
```

Whan am I doing wrong?

**edit**: my bad I was running the script as:

```
Python pmake.py
```

rather than the script directly to run the 3.6 version

Comment: this is python 2.7, right? then there should be no parenthesis; otherwise you print a `tuple` containing the `repr` of your objects.

Comment: You must be using Python 2, so the parentheses are unnecessary. You can just `print "Password set", ps_file_name`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist python 3.6

Comment: @S.Redrum If it were Python 3, you wouldn't be having this problem. It must be Python 2.

Comment: @khelwood I noticed I have both `2.7` and `3.6` versions how do I make the `3.6` version effective as default in windows?

Comment: [Works in Python 3](https://ideone.com/wwOcVf), [not so much in Python 2.7](https://ideone.com/uaIkEE)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove parentheses and comma from printed output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260208/how-to-remove-parentheses-and-comma-from-printed-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because print write a tuple when given more than one argument

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "world"
print (str1, str2) #will print : (hello, world)
```

What you want is to

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "world"
str3 = str1 + str2
print (str3) #will print : Hello world
```

Or rather

```
print (str1 + str2)  #see how you give only one argument by concatenating str1 and str2 ?
```

Note though that if you want to add up two object that are not strings themselves, you will have to cast them into strings (make as if there were strings). Even if both object would print correctly alone. 
It is because python can't add up two stuff that are not compatible.

```
x = "your picture is"
y = someimage.jpg
print(x,y) # works well and dandy, gives a tuple
print(x + y)#fails, python can t add up a string and an image
print(x + str(y))# works because str(y) is y casted into a string
```

Note though that not everything can be casted into a string